# Odoo customize WMS for user interface

Tags: odoo-8

I am very new in Odoo (OpenERP), I have to develop a system based on warehouse management system. I know i can develop different Modules and inherit them, but can someone help me for good tutorial.

I want to know that is it possible to create own user interface for WMS Module, so that i can create my own UI and connect to different pages.
Sorry I don't know much about ODOO.

Thanks,
Maverick

Comment: in ODOO you can change the view by overriding  the base.css , it will change your ODOO UI experience

Comment: Thanks Prakash, I just want to know that as i am novice, just a high level, if i have to create login screen for small screen for warehouse. Do I have to create new module and override base.css to adapt small screen. if yes, then what happens if you access in desktop screen.

Comment: if your are aware about "media query in css" and "bootstrap" , then multi-screen will never be problem .

Comment: Hi Prakash, Thanks again. I know media queries. Can you please guide me in high level approach that how to build user interface for barcode scanner in warehouse. I mean do i have to create my own modules or basically the way it is done. as I am from PHP background and i see things like clicking goes to different pages and etc.

Comment: If you have enough time, you can build your own interface and use Odoo's JSONRPC interface to communicate with the server. So it could be a php interface, if php has libaries or plugins for jsonrpc communication